# Old mobile no is being displayed on UI and also passed in OTP verification step

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so the flow is i have a multi step form in which it validate each step perfectly and then go to the next step but in last step there is a verification on the sim that the number must be registered on your national identity number if it does not verify it redirects the user to the first screen in which it get the value of cellNo from the input field when i update the number and then go to next step it calls the update api

```
if (isSimNotVerfied) {
  props.updatePhoneNumber({
    applicationId: applicationId,
    phone: applicants[0].cellNo,
    phoneCountryCode: "92",
    mobileOperator: applicants[0].mobileOperator.value,
  });
```

so it will call this api without otp and it only calls when isSimNotVerfied == true and it becomes true when simVerification failed in the last step so what i passed in the phone field applicants[0].cellNo is my state field which I'm updating and then it saves the updated value in the state and call the api

and then when i enter otp it again call this api and pass otp as well

```
  const handleOtpChange = (value) => {
  if (value.length == 4) {
  if (isSimNotVerfied) {
    props.updatePhoneNumber({
      applicationId: applicationId,
      phone: state.applicantList[0].cellNo,
      phoneCountryCode: "92",
      otp: value,
    });
  } else {
    props.verifyCustomerInfoOtp({
      applicationId: applicationId,
      otp: value,
    });
  }
}
setState({ ...state, mobileOtp: value });
};
```

now it call the api with the otp value and but the issue is this api does not call because in my UI it get the cell Number from the application object but in that object phone number does not change and it is a get endpoint it

```
 <Authentication
          redirectTo={redirectTo}
          resendOtp={resendOtp}
          execStatusSentEmailConfirmation={execStatusSentEmailConfirmation}
          execStatusGetApplicationStatus={execStatusGetApplicationStatus}
          validationCheck={validationCheck}
          execStatusGetConfigurations={execStatusGetConfigurations}
          execStatusAddBasicCustomerInfo={execStatusAddBasicCustomerInfo}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          handleAccountChange={handleAccountChange}
          proceedToNextStep={proceedToNextStep}
          handleBasicInfoSubmit={handleBasicInfoSubmit}
          handleOtpChange={handleOtpChange}
          resetStateOtp={resetStateOtp}
          closeProceedDialog={closeProceedDialog}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          {...props}
          {...state.applicantList[0]}
          {...state}
          // {...state.applicantList[parseInt(stepNumber) - 1]}
          goBack={goBack}
          numberOfApplicants={state.numberOfApplicants}
          validationResult={state.validationResultBasicDetail}
          // {...state.applicantList[currentActiveStep]}
        />
```

this is my authentication component this is called after the phone number update

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import OtpInput from "react-otp-input";
import { IsMobileWidth, IsZoom150 } from 'components/common/util/util'
import { useState } from 'react';
import EmailVerification from './email.verification/email.verification';
import ResendOtp from 'components/common/resend.otp/resend.otp'


export default function Authentication(props) {
const mobileWidth = IsMobileWidth()
const zoom150 = IsZoom150()

const { mobileOtp, otpSuccess, account, cellNo,resendAppId,resendType,email } = props

    if(cellNo === '') {
    props.history.push("/dob")
}

useEffect(() => {
     return () => {
        props.resetStateOtp()
     }
},[])

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {
            otpSuccess  ?
                <EmailVerification
                    {...props}
                    
                /> :
                <div className='w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pt-5'>
                    <div className='d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center'>
                        <div>
                            <Typography className='fw-bolder' color="primary">Verify your mobile number</Typography>
                        </div>
                        <div className='pt-2 fw-bolder pt-2'>
                            <Typography>Please enter the OTP we sent to +92 {cellNo}
                            </Typography>
                        </div>
                        <div className='pt-2'>
                            <OtpInput
                                isInputSecure={false}
                                // isDisabled={execStatus.status === "PENDING" ? true : false}
                                shouldAutoFocus={true}
                                isInputNum={true}
                                onChange={props.handleOtpChange}
                                // numInputs={length}
                                value={mobileOtp}
                                resetStateOtp = {props.resetStateOtp}
                                separator={<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                                inputStyle={{
                                    width: mobileWidth || zoom150 ? 40 : 40,
                                    height: mobileWidth || zoom150 ? 40 : 40,
                                    backgroundColor: "#EDEDEC",
                                    border: "none",
                                    borderRadius: 10,

                                    // fontFamily: state.visibility ? "password" : "text",
                                }}
                                focusStyle={{
                                    borderRadius: 10,
                                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                                    outline: "none",
                                    boxShadow:
                                        "0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <ResendOtp
                            applicationId={props.basicInfoSignUpResponse && props.basicInfoSignUpResponse.get("applicationId")}
                            type="SIGNUP" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        }
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

this is my authentication component is there any way i can get the updated value in a separate variable and pass that variable in the authentication component and then print it but it only works if the isSimNotVerified true then i pass the variable otherwise use the state variable how can i do that?